# Exempt several site folders from forced https://

Tags: .htaccess

A year ago I managed to figure out what to add to .htaccess to force https:// on my site.  I thought it was working. (Green code)

Last week, however, I noticed that some pages were still coming up as http://

I had someone "fix" it.  They added the blue code. And, yes, all pages are now coming up as https://. BUT, the four URLs in the original code that we don't want to be forced to https are now being forced to https://

Is there a simple way to modify the blue code so that the four folders are not forced to https// ??[[image: Code screen capture[1]]

I tried moving the four RewriteCond {REQUEST_URI} lines from the green to blue section, but that didn't help.

And, I can safely remove the original code now, right?

Comment: Where did you try moving the four `RewriteCond` lines (as in, before/after which lines)?

Comment: @rink.attendant.6: I moved the four lines to just above both of the </IfModule> lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`RewriteCond`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) rules are processed as a conjunction (a set of `and` expressions) up to the [`RewriteRule`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) directive.

> The `RewriteCond` directive defines a rule condition. One or more `RewriteCond` can precede a [`RewriteRule`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule)  directive. The following rule is then only used if both the current state of the URI matches its pattern, **and** if these conditions are met.

Therefore, they need to be placed before the RewriteRule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond ...
RewriteCond ...
RewriteCond ...
RewriteCond ...
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [E=UPGRADE,L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks!! That fixed it.  A bit embarassed here to be such a "script kiddie"  

Have you a favorite charity to which I can donate a few dollars? (Or is that against TOS here?)